# Trying To Install Homebrew But Ran Into Issues

Tags: terminal, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I installed Homebrew and as per the instructions ran `brew doctor` to find some issues.

Then I ran `brew prune` and moved Macports.

Apparently uninstalling Macports can cause more issues. It's in a new directory. What should I do with it?

This is what is happening:

```
~ $ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/bin/bbdiff
  /usr/local/bin/bbedit
  /usr/local/bin/bbfind
  /usr/local/bin/mate
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/bbdiff.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/bbedit.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/bbfind.1

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/stdint-msvc2008.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-bsd.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-darwin.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-linux.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-sunos.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
~ $ brew prune
Pruned 0 dead formulae
Pruned 7 symbolic links from /usr/local
~ $ sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports
Password:
~ $ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/stdint-msvc2008.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-bsd.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-darwin.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-linux.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-sunos.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
```

Can anyone tell me my next steps? What are "Unexpected header files?"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? If you are trying to install something, just try again now that you have fixed some of the problems.

Comment: Hey Mark,

My goal was to install the Homebrew version of Git and then update my $PATH to use the Brew version and not the Apple version.

Comment: Have you retried installing git now you have cured some problems? Have you tried to install `node` using `homebrew` or `macports`? Do you need `node`?

Comment: Mark, I haven't gotten around to it yet. Between having 3 critters (i.e. kids) and my Christmas/freelance schedule it's been tough to get back. But I'm chomping at the bit. Maybe I can get to it tonight or tomorrow night. Is the Apple version of Git really not that flexible?